# Using a Vlookup to return a mismatched answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

So I am looking up IDs between 2 different tabs and I need to return the value if the vlookup doesn't work instead of just a #NA.

[image]

Comment: Michelle, this makes no sense.  The VLOOKUP() formula that you show can't work the way you indicate.  VLOOOKUP() always tries to find the lookup value (12345 here, I think) in the *first* column of the lookup array.  Here that is Column A of Sheet 2, a list of names.  So the formula won't find *any* numbers there and will return #N/A for everything.  It might be that I'm misunderstanding the way you've tried to display your data.  If so, please explain it more clearly.

Comment: HI - I have put the wrong lookup value column - it should have said A2.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iferror()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) with the value you want as the fall back.

Syntax

```
IFERROR(value, value_if_error)
```

Example

```
=IFERROR(A2/B2, "Error in calculation")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your request is more simpler than it sounds or more complicated.

Why it might be simpler:
If sheet 2 data already contains the correct answer, then you don't need to compare to Sheet 1 data, just get the sheet 2 data.

Why it might be complicated: 
If you are doing this to error check and you have to manually determine the right value then maybe syntax like this could be a start but only if names are in both sheets and no duplicates within each sheet:

```
 =if(vlookup(table3Name,table1,2,false)=vlookup(table3Name,table2,2,false), "",vlookup(table3Name,table2,2,false))
```

However, if you are doing error checking, then I suggest you have three columns in the results table (in place of your one ID column) column 1 would be Table 1 ID (vlookup), column 2 would be Table 2 ID (vlookup) and column three would be the check column (if).

Again, you need to further assess your data and if there are duplicates within a table, or if names are not in both sheets, then you'll need a different syntax for the error check column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I am doing error checking.  And there are duplicates.  I will see if there is a way to have unique values by doing concatenate or something like that for my lookup values.